# How to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 - \sin x}{2}$ does not exist

Tags: limits

Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 - \sin x}{2}$ does not exist.

I got the question to show that the lim doesn’t exist by $f’(x)/g’(x)$ with the function $f(x) = x + \cos(x)$ and $g(x) = 2x$. My idea is in the appendix.[image]

It that idea right, can someone check it?

Comment: This is a nice example to go with the study of L'Hopital's rule.  A certain converse can fail.  In this example, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) =\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) =\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, that is the way, we should learn. Is my idea right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its wrong, the bounds go like $$-1\leq \sin x\leq 1\implies 1\geq -\sin x\geq -1\implies 1\geq \frac{1-\sin x}{2}\geq 0,$$ so you dont get any contradiction. Take $x_n=n\pi$ and $y_n=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}$. Both of them goes to $\infty$ when $n$ does, but $$\frac{1-\sin x_n}{2}=1/2, $$ and $$\frac{1-\sin y_n}{2}=0, $$ so the limit doesnt exist.

Comment: But it is not easier to take 1 >= - sin(x) >= -1 and than to take the limits to have 0 >= (1-sin(x))/2 >= 1 and then we have not a specific limit, so the function diverges

Comment: Take what limit exactly? $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x$ does not exist, by a similar argument that mine's. Also to have a limit such as is bounded by $0$ and $1$ is not a contradiction

Comment: Yeah, sorry it is not a contradiction, I mean we can’t get an clear limit, because it bounces between 0 and 1 so it is like my version

Comment: If you want $\sin y_n = 1$, you need to set $y_n = \frac{(4n - 1)\pi}{2}$.  Setting $y_n = \frac{(2n - 1)\pi}{2}$ causes $\sin y_n$ to alternate between the values $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: No, your version is wrong. You proved that the expresion $\frac{1-\sin x}{2}$ is never well defined, it clearly does not make sense

Comment: But it is not so, that it shows that we have not an clear limit?